# Missing write permissions in home/user/anaconda2

Tags: 14.04, python, opencv

I am trying to install opencv using the command

```
conda install opencv
```

This command worked on my laptop, but i am getting following error when I try it on my desktop computer. Both systems are running Ubuntu 14.04

```
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ....................
Package plan for installation in environment /home/ws2/anaconda2:

The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
openssl-1.0.2e             |                0         3.2 MB  defaults
sqlite-3.9.2               |                0         3.9 MB  defaults
numpy-1.10.2               |           py27_0         5.9 MB  defaults
requests-2.9.1             |           py27_0         605 KB  defaults
setuptools-19.4            |           py27_0         365 KB  defaults
conda-3.19.0               |           py27_0         176 KB  defaults
opencv-2.4.10              |      np110py27_1         9.2 MB  defaults
pip-8.0.1                  |           py27_0         1.5 MB  defaults
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        24.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

opencv:     2.4.10-np110py27_1 defaults (soft-link)

The following packages will be UPDATED:

conda:      3.18.8-py27_0 defaults --> 3.19.0-py27_0      defaults (soft-link)
numpy:      1.10.1-py27_0 defaults --> 1.10.2-py27_0      defaults (soft-link)
openssl:    1.0.2d-0      defaults --> 1.0.2e-0           defaults (soft-link)
pip:        7.1.2-py27_0  defaults --> 8.0.1-py27_0       defaults (soft-link)
requests:   2.8.1-py27_0  defaults --> 2.9.1-py27_0       defaults (soft-link)
setuptools: 18.5-py27_0   defaults --> 19.4-py27_0        defaults (soft-link)
sqlite:     3.8.4.1-1     defaults --> 3.9.2-0            defaults (soft-link)

Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/ws2/anaconda2
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to install packages
# into the install area '/home/ws2/anaconda2'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/ws2/anaconda2
```

Comment: What is this 'conda' command you're using?

Comment: Conda is an open source package management system and environment management system for installing multiple versions of software packages and their dependencies and switching easily between them. [link] (http://conda.pydata.org/docs/)

Comment: Did you install conda from the official Ubuntu repos? Otherwise, it's hard to see this a Ubuntu question,  that should be handled in this community.

BTW, did you try the command the help text hinted to: `conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/ws2/anaconda2`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that somehow "anaconda2" folder where "anaconda" is installed, was set to 'access only' because the owner of "anaconda2" folder was "root". Now I have changed the ownership of "anaconda2" folder by using command

```
sudo chown -R ws2 anaconda
sudo chown -R usr foldername
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try running your command using `sudo`, like this:

```
  sudo conda install opencv
```

Comment: conda doesn't work with sudo

Comment: You can make this work with a root user, you usually just need to provide the correct `PATH` for the root user, using `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda install ...`.  If you aren't sure what this is doing, probably best not to use it!

Answer (score 0):

follow the following commands and work accordingly whenever there comes an issue related to these permission.
what i have done here is i changed the permission of all files and subfolders of 'pkgs' folder in anaconda directories.
**sudo chown -R 'user': /home/user/anaconda/pkgs**

this worked for me 
in your case do

**sudo chown -R ws2: /home/ws2/anaconda2**